# Unity game crashing during load on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, build, unity-game-engine, prime31

I'm developing in Unity 3.4.2f, XCode version 4.2.1 with iOS 5.0 SDK.

My game consists of a main menu with a play button that loads the main scene.  The game can be built to device by a co-worker and works just fine.  Whenever *I* build the game though, it crashes while loading the second scene.  This has been the bane of my existence for over a week now.

the crash log from the device looks like this:

```
    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGILL)
    Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00ed4e90
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   ???                             0x050000c0 0 + 83886272
    1   ???                             0xfffffff8 0 + -8

    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33babfbc kevent + 24
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x328ebed4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 744
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x328ecf3a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 70
    3   libdispatch.dylib               0x328ec4ec _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 228
    4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3489f58a _pthread_wqthread + 258
    5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3489fbbc start_wqthread + 0

    *Note: Removed various other non-crashed threads through thread 11*

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x01ab7094    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3f800000
    r4: 0x04020000    r5: 0x3987cc80      r6: 0x01004d08      r7: 0x080000c1
    r8: 0xc1080000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0xc1050000     r11: 0xc1040000
    ip: 0x2fdfe144    sp: 0x00ed4e9c      lr: 0x00dfc558      pc: 0x050000c0
    cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Which is not the most helpful, but from what i've been reading here and various other sites, I SHOULD be able to use those memory addresses like 0x050000c0 to determine where in the actual code i'm crashing?  First some other things we've tried...

The project is in an SVN repo, so I've blown away the entire source dir and re-updated it from SVN, ensuring the coworker who CAN build properly has done the same.  When that didn't work, I had him send me a .zip of his xcode project, to try building that, but the Prime31 Unity plugins don't like that, they point to his source folder which is in a different user dir on his machine.  So I had him zip up his unity source and send that along, which required a re-install of the Prime31 plugins, and then I was able to build, but still with the same results.  Crashing between scene loads.

We are both using the exact same physical iPad device to build on.  We are both building against iOS 5.0, while the device is 4.3.3.

I have gone as far as deleting all xcode setting, then deleting the entire /Developer folder from my Mac and reinstalled xcode completely.  Same results.  I would try reinstalling Unity, but I'm not sure if I would need to get my Unity Pro key deactivated and then reactivated again?

I have spent far too much time for this to be something complex and difficult.  I know it is certainly something that is incomprehensibly simple and stupid on my part, but I can no longer see the forest for the trees, so I am asking you, dear Internets!

Comment: Just add your own solution as answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved! I linked this post to a friend who asked, "Are you SURE you're both on the same unity version?" I checked, and I was in fact on Unity version 3.4.1f and not 3.4.2f. Updated Unity and all was well. Presumably the latest version of these Prime31 plugins do not like the older version of Unity?

Comment: Have you tried to make a iOS build form Unity3D Windows environment? (to explain it to you: I have the Unity3D project which was made from a Windows machine and trying to make a build form my iOS device on my MAC machine). Let me know please, thanks! ;)